# Find x,y,z velocity component of a star?

Tags: orbit, velocity

I am trying to find the initial x,y,z velocity components of the Epsilon Lyrae stars. How might I go about doing this? The radial velocities are available on Wikipedia, but I am not sure how to use that data for my purpose.

Comment: Do you mean the cartesian coordinates of each component of the binary or of the system relative to the Solar System or to the Galactic Center ? To put it another way: what's the origin of the x,y,z system that you want ?

Comment: @astrosnapper I mean the cartesian coordinates of each component

Comment: I think you didn't understand astrosnapper's question; "To put it another way: what's the origin...?"

Comment: I might be missing something, but, for velocity, the origin wouldn't matter, although the orientation would (ie, the directions in which the x, y, and z axes point)

Comment: Along with clearing up the orientation of the coordinates to use, you'll want to get the proper motion of the stars in addition to the radial velocity.

Comment: This needs clarifying. What do you mean by "initial velocity"? This is a multiple system where the stars "orbit" each other.